# How to add email validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

im am a newbie to javascript, i write a code to add a validation to my form, this is my script:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var name=document.forms["form"]["entry.1017659850"].value;
    var email=document.forms["form"]["entry.808043133"].value;
    var check=document.forms["form"]["entry.317648050"].checked;

    if(name == ""){
        document.getElementById("alertname").style.display="block";
        return false;
    }

    if(email == ""){
        document.getElementById("alertemail").style.display="block";
        return false;
    }

    if(!check){
        document.getElementById("alertcheck").style.display="block";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And i want to add my email validation

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

The question is how will i do it, i am not familiar with the functions on javascript.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

function validateForm()
{
    var name=document.forms["form"]["entry.1017659850"].value;
    var email=document.forms["form"]["entry.808043133"].value;
    var check=document.forms["form"]["entry.317648050"].checked;

    if(name == ""){
        document.getElementById("alertname").style.display="block";
        return false;
    }

    if(email == ""){
        document.getElementById("alertemail").style.display="block";
        return false;
    }

    if(!check){
        document.getElementById("alertcheck").style.display="block";
        return false;
    }

    if(!validateEmail(email)){
        document.getElementById("alertemail").style.display="block";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.test()` returns a boolean. If it doesn't match the given regex, it will return false, so you can use its return value to know if it validates or not:

```
if(email == "" || !validateEmail(email)){
    document.getElementById("alertemail").style.display="block";
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your email like this. I got this from [here](https://insidethediv.com/email-validation-on-javascript).

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    const pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return pattern.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

var email = "-9i{@ssss.ss";
var is_valid = validateEmail(email);

if(is_valid === true){
    console.log("Yes Valid Email")
}else{
    console.log("Not Valid Email")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var email = "abc@abc.com";
  if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email)) 
    {
        alert("invalid");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("valid");
    }
```